# Istio cuts the request with large response after two minutes

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, istio, istio-gateway, istio-sidecar

I have a Kubernetes environment with Istio gateway set up. I've stumbled upon an issue that I can't seem to resolve.

We created a Nodejs Backend microservice that serves an API and one of the API endpoints can serve a large response of 100MB+. All our microservice deployments are supported with Istio Proxy sidecars.

First approach that I tried was using a streamed response. When I make a request to this API and I know I can expect such a big response, it always gets cut of after two minutes (or at about 96MB of streamed response).

Another approach that I took was to build the response in the Backend and then return the response as whole, but with similar failed response after two minutes. Interestingly, I could observe in the logs of the Backend that the `Request aborted by the client`, and then the Istio gateway retries to send the same request with the same Id to the Backend two more times, which fail the same way.

If I `curl` the request directly on the Pod, so bypassing the Gateway completely, I receive the full response of 109 MB after about 2 minutes and 39 seconds without any issue, so this reassures my theory that the issue is somewhere on the Gateway level.

I've tried manually to set the Timeout limit to 300s on the Virtual Service that I'm using in case it would, but the result is the same nevertheless.

My second option was to try to increase the number `failureTreshold` configuration of readiness Probe on Istio Proxy sidecar, in case the health request times out, before the request is finished, which also didn't result to anything positive in this case.

I have checked the logs of Istio sidecar and I believe that something is happening there. In this screenshot you can see, that the whole connection gets recreated - this is what happens after two minutes
[image: Istio Sidecar logs]

Here is a complete log: [istio.log](https://accesa-my.sharepoint.com/personal/alecs_tusciuc_accesa_eu/_layouts/15/onedrive.aspx?ga=1&id=%2Fpersonal%2Falecs%5Ftusciuc%5Faccesa%5Feu%2FDocuments%2Fistio%2Elog&parent=%2Fpersonal%2Falecs%5Ftusciuc%5Faccesa%5Feu%2FDocuments)

I hope somebody can help me with me issues as I am running out of ideas what could be causing this issue. If there are any additional information needed I will gladly provide.

Comment: Do you have another load balance in front of the gateway, like an AWS ALB? If it's retrying the request, that means you have enabled retries which is also likely where your timeout is set https://istio.io/latest/docs/concepts/traffic-management/#retries

Comment: @jordanm thank you for pointing that out. I am fairly new at all this - how can I see if there is any load balancer in front of it?
I checked the 'retries' but my Virtual Service doesn't have anything set.

Comment: Check the istio gateway service to see if its a type `LoadBalancer`. If you're in a cloud hosted env, than there most likely is one.

Comment: @jordanm yes, you're right, there is a Service called 'istio-ingressgateway' which is of type LoadBalancer. how can I know if this Load Balancer is causing my issue? also if so, I was checking what options are there for configuration of the load balancer, but I couldn't find any solution.

Comment: That depends on your env and what kind of load balancer it is. If you're in AWS and using aws-load-balancer-controller, you want to adjust the [idle_timeout](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.4/guide/ingress/annotations/#custom-attributes) custom attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my example I was using also OAuth2 Client for the authorization which was implemented in the Kubernetes using Istio in combination with Oathkeeper and it was Oathkeeper that was having a timeout configured to 120 seconds.
As I didn't have the permissions to change the resources of the Oathkeeper my solution was to manually paginate the large response and stream it to the client.